# how to detect changed radio input value with ng-model when its value is initialised after fetching some data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am fetching some data from the server and based on that i am initialising the ng-value of input which is shown after the data is fetched. But after that when I call a function with `ng-change`, console log doesn't show the changed value of the `ng-model="chosedOption"`. It continues to print "Paytm Blance" even after selecting other radio buttons. 
**angular js file**

```
var app = angular.module("formModule", []);

var formController = ($scope, $http) => {

    $scope.chosedOption = "Paytm Balance";
    $scope.amount = 10;
    $scope.resJson = "";
    $scope.payOptions = undefined;

    $scope.proceed = (chosedOption) => {
        console.log(chosedOption);
        console.log($scope.chosedOption);

    }

    $scope.loadDoc = () => {
        const orderId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 100000;
        const data = {
            amount: $scope.amount,
            orderId: orderId
        }
        $http.post("http://localhost:3200/intiate_transaction_api",data)
            .then(response => {
                $scope.resJson = JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4);
                console.log(response);
                let data = {
                    txnToken: response.data.body.txnToken,
                    orderId: orderId
                }
                $http.post('http://localhost:3200/fetch_payment_option_api', data)
                .then(response2 => {
                    $scope.resJson = JSON.stringify(response2, undefined, 4);
                    $scope.payOptions = response2.data.body.merchantPayOption.paymentModes;
                })
            })

    }
}
app.controller("formController", formController);

app.filter('safeHtml', $sce => {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    }
})
```

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>UI</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="formModule" ng-controller="formController">
    <div class="result">
        <div class="container">
            <form name="amt" action="#"></form>
            total amount<input type="text" id="amount" ng-model="amount" name="amount">
            <button ng-click="loadDoc()">Pay</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="payOtions" ng-if="payOptions">
        <div ng-repeat="option in payOptions">
            <label>
                <div  class="paymentOption" ng-class="">
                    <input name="payOption"
                           ng-change="proceed(option.displayName)"
                           ng-model="chosedOption" type="radio"
                           ng-value="option.displayName">
                    {{option.displayName}}
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre><code id="demo" ng-bind-html="resJson | safeHtml"></code></pre>
    <script src="./angularScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**output**
[can be checked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vhOT.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-change` directive only listens to changes made by the user. It does not listen to changes made by the controller.

Any changes done by the controller should call the listening function from the controller.